# Convert Outdoor Light Fixture to Plug

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture, troubleshooting, cord-and-plug

[image: Current Overview of Work Site]

1. I would like to switch this light fixture to a plug that doesn't require screwing it in like a light bulb.
2. The plug and assembly must be compatible with a 2"clearance between the wall and roof of the adjacent structure.
3. It should be suitable for outdoor use and withstand the weather.
4. The current box has an octagonal shape with dimensions of 3.5" x 3.5".
5. The light is currently wired to two switches and may be removed in the future.
6. Ideally, the existing box in the wall will be retained, but it may be necessary to install a new box that can be screwed into the brick surface.
7. I require guidance on what exact products to purchase for this project. Due to the clearance limitation, none of the previously suggested solutions appear viable.
8. Would be up to code with general North American standards.

Any help you can provide would be great, and I can answer any details I may have missed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a *GFCI/receptacle* in that location because GFCI reset has to be reachable. I can't find the code reference at the moment, but based on various related references, that may be anywhere from 5-1/2 feet to 8 feet. Even if this does turn out to be (barely) within the limit, I highly recommend against putting a GFCI/receptacle in that location. Instead, put an ordinary, weather-resistant, receptacle there and put the GFCI elsewhere. That will give you a bit more flexibility in finding something that will fit.

But you definitely need GFCI on a *receptacle* if it is outside. That is not the case, generally, for hard-wired lighting. Which does leave open the question of: *Why do you need this to be a receptacle instead of a light fixture?* There are a number of different possible reasons:

- Plug in a permanent light fixture. I don't recommend this in general, but sometimes it makes sense indoors. It rarely makes sense outdoors.
- Plug in holiday lights or other temporary stuff. That actually makes sense, and may work well with the receptacle being switched.
- Plug in something totally unrelated, such as a security camera. In this case, you have additional issues because you generally don't want things like a security camera to be switchable. On the other hand, there are alternatives such as Power-over-Ethernet which allow easier cabling than regular 120V AC and can provide communications as well as power.

Back to the GFCI. GFCI can be placed anywhere accessible (not too high, not behind an installed appliance like a dishwasher) in the circuit and protect everything following it in the circuit. This includes:

- GFCI/breaker - usually the most expensive but, assuming your panel has them available, easiest to install and protects the entire circuit.
- GFCI/receptacle - replace an earlier receptacle in the circuit, ideally indoors so the GFCI will last longer
- GFCI/deadfront - add in a convenient location, ideally indoors so the GFCI will last longer

One possibility is to install a GFCI/receptacle next to, or possibly in place of, one of the existing switches. But it could get a bit complicated as you have 3-way switches and there are many possible ways they can be configured.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I had mistakenly believed that a GFCI was required for outdoor use, but I now realize that you are correct that may not be so. I will revise my post to reflect that a GFCI plug is unnecessary and hope to find someone who can recommend the appropriate product or setup for our needs. Your input on this matter is greatly appreciated, and I am grateful for your valuable advice.

Comment: GFCI _protection_ is needed, but the GFCI device proper can be upstream, even a GFCI breaker in your panel.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add clarification in lay-terms...The "receptacle" needs to be GFCI protected. That means either the receptacle itself is a GFCI receptacle, but the location you want it places it out of normal access to reset it. It needs to be "readily accessible". Another option would be to have an indoor receptacle on the same circuit be a GFCI receptacle IF the outdoor receptacle was wired down-stream of it. Since yours is currently an outdoor switched light, that scenario also wouldn't apply.
Yet another option would be to replace the existing breaker serving the light with a GFCI breaker. These are more expensive, but in order to do what you want, it may be the best and easiest option.
More options?...You can extend the circuit a few feet lower and put a GFCI receptacle within accessible reach, then run the circuit back up and put another receptacle in the light's place. If wired correctly, the top receptacle would now be GFCI protected, with the GFCI receptacle being accessible.